# Select An Optional Parent Row Using Same Table

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to select all rows from a table and also include some information about their parent in the same row **if they have a parent** otherwise the parent data should be blank.

```
SELECT
p.id,
p.name,
'0' AS page_exists      
FROM 
pages p
    LEFT JOIN pages pp ON (pp.page_id=p.parent) 
WHERE 
p.page_type=3 
ORDER BY 
name ASC
```

I would like upon a successful match for the parent to add the following two columns to each row:
"parent_id" and "parent_name"

**The end result for a page with a parent would look like this:**

```
id=2
name="test"
page_exists=0   
parent_id=1
parent_name="abc"
```

**If a page does not have a parent it should look like this:**

```
id=3
name="other page"
page_exists=0   
parent_id=0
parent_name=""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do a `LEFT JOIN`of the table to itself, using the alias pp for the parent information, the fields from the parent row is available as `pp.page_id`and `pp.name`, both being `NULL` if a parent does not exist.

Thus, the following query will include the fields from the parent:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, '0' AS page_exists,
       pp.page_id AS parent_id, pp,name AS parent_name      
FROM pages p
LEFT JOIN pages pp 
ON (pp.page_id=p.parent) 
WHERE p.page_type=3 
ORDER BY name ASC
```

In order to get 0 and '' instead of `NULL`s when a parent does not exist, you can use `CASE` statements in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT pp.id, pp.name, '0' AS page_exists,
      CASE WHEN pp.page_id THEN pp.page_ID ELSE 0 END AS parent_id,
      CASE WHEN pp.name THEN pp.name ELSE '' AS parent_name
```